# USB C 3.1 Gen 1 to DVI

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, dvi, docking-station, display-adapter

I recently purchased [i-Tec USB C Travel Adapter](https://www.i-tec-europe.eu/?t=3&v=424) for my [ASUS T100HA](https://www.asus.com/Commercial-Notebooks/ASUS_Transformer_Book_T100HA/).

As this tablet has no USB C 3.1 Gen 2 support (DP/PD), I could not use the HDMI port included in that dock or charge it using the PD port.

After a little bit of research I found [LogiLink USB C to DVI adapter (UA0245)](http://logilink.eu/Suche/UA0245) which was supposed to support USB 3.1 Gen 1. However, after connecting it to the ASUS, I still couldn't get the display to work (I used a DVI-D to DVI-D Single Link cable). I also tried to connect it via the USB C port in the i-Tec dock. Please note the Ethernet adapter and USB 3.0 ports on the dock are working flawlessly - I'm getting 100Mbps/10Mbps on speedtest.net and one of the USB 3.0 ports have a nano receiver for wireless keyboard and mouse.

I am wondering if [this i-Tec DVI adapter](https://www.i-tec-europe.eu/?t=3&v=221) would resolve my issue as it's USB 3.0. It would be ideal if I could connect ASUS to the i-tec dock and then use one of its USB 3.0 ports to connect the i-tec DVI adapter.

I'm starting to run out of ideas. Is USB C Gen 1 capable of transferring ANY video?

Answer (score 1):

I purchased a Asus UX360UA/Q324UAK laptop recently with a similar USB-C port. I also purchased a USB-C to VGA/USB3.0/USB-C hub, but couldn't figure out how to work it. After attempting several driver upgrade/rollbacks, I contacted Asus directly.

Quote:
I regret to inform you that the device is not compatible.
  The USB-C is not display enable .
The USB specs are as follow:
1 x USB-C Gen 1 (up to 5 Gbps)

Comment: Oh, the USB-C may be "not display enable"? Thank you, I did not know that.