# USB 3.0 to USB-3.1 (type-c) to HDMI

Tags: hdmi, dvi, usb-3, displayport, usb-3.1-type-c

I have USB-3.0 ports on my computer and I need to get an extra HDMI 2.0 port to connect another 4K screen.

I have option to buy USB-3.0 to HDMI connector and it will cost me around $100.

Or

I can by a connector USB-3.0 to USB-3.1 (type-c) for $5 plus another connector USB-3.1 (type-c) to HDMI for another $10.

If it will work I'll save around $85.

But will it work? Why?

P.S.

I'll be happy with a HDMI, DisplayPort or DVI and (2560 × 1600) is fine, if there would be solution. But (1920 × 1080) - is not enough.

Comment: There are $20 USB3 to HDMI adapters on Amazon.  However, your not going to get 4K resolution out of HDMI 2 over USB.

Comment: Yes, they only offer (1920 × 1080) it is not enough for modern monitors.

Comment: Even USB-C may be "[not display enable](https://superuser.com/questions/1201874/usb-c-3-1-gen-1-to-dvi?rq=1)".

Comment: Seems like you have answered your own question.  USB Type-C will still be limited by the fact it’s USB 3.  You gain no performance from the Type-C connector.  The $100 adapter will absolutely not get you 4k

Comment: The only 4K Type-C adapters are actually Thunderbolt 3 adapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that not all USB-C ports are able to carry a `video signal`. You will need to connect to a port that is labeled with one of the icons below.

[image]
or
[image]

[link](https://us.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/48481/~/how-to-connect-a-computer-with-usb-c-port-to-an-external-display)

Comment: Different manufacturers will use different icons to mark USB-C ports that are capable of video output.  This is confusing and unfortunate.  While Acer and Apple (as two examples) will use the Thunderbolt icon to indicate a DisplayPort video capable port there is nothing in the Thunderbolt spec that requires a Thunderbolt port to support DisplayPort video.  I am not aware of any computer models that do not provide DisplayPort video on Thunderbolt capable ports but that may only demonstrate my ignorance of such computers.  Also note that not all USB-C cables are able to carry a video signal.

Answer (score 0):

> I have USB-3.0 ports on my computer and I need to get an extra HDMI 2.0 port to connect another 4K screen.
>
> I have option to buy USB-3.0 to HDMI connector and it will cost me
> around $100.

That sounds about the right price range for a DisplayLink adapter.  I haven't used DisplayLink adapters myself but I read good things about them.  DisplayLink makes a number of chips for adapting USB to HDMI, DisplayPort, VGA, or whatever.  A number of dock and dongle makers use the these same family of chips from DisplayLink and given the reviews it's a good option.

> Or
>
> I can by a connector USB-3.0 to USB-3.1 (type-c) for $5 plus another
> connector USB-3.1 (type-c) to HDMI for another $10.
>
> If it will work I'll save around $85.
>
> But will it work? Why?

Not likely.

When I read about people with their adapters for their computer I think of my brother with his camper and his adapters.  It's a big camper and so it has a 240 volt 50 amp plug for "shore power".  But not all camping spots have that kind of plug so he has a shoebox full of power adapters, from a number of 30 amp plugs, a couple 20 amp plugs, and even a common household 15 amp plug.  He can adapt this big plug down to a 120 volt 15 amp outlet, like the kind you'd use to plug in a table lamp, but does that mean my brother can run his camper's air conditioner, microwave oven, refrigerator, turn on all the lights, and crank up the stereo with that adapter?  Of course not.  He has to keep his electrical usage down to 120 volt 15 amp or the circuit breaker trips.

That USB-C adapter still leaves you with the same USB 3.0 capability as the USB-A port it was plugged into.  To get video out of it still means needing a $100 DisplayLink video adapter.

> P.S.
>
> I'll be happy with a HDMI, DisplayPort or DVI and (2560 × 1600) is
> fine, if there would be solution. But (1920 × 1080) - is not enough.

To get HDMI, DVI, DP, or VGA from USB-A means using some kind of DisplayLink chip or something like it.  If you have a USB-C port on your computer then that doesn't necessarily open your options much since there are plenty of USB-C ports that lack support for any video output.  Those that do support video output on USB-C is nearly certainly DisplayPort (or "DP" for short).

If DP works for you then a cable from your DP capable USB-C port to some DP capable display should be cheap and easy.  If you want HDMI then you'll need an active adapter.  There are passive adapters that will allow one to plug an DP cable into a HDMI socket, that doesn't mean one will get video.  The "full size" DP ports on the backs of computers for years often had that funny looking "DP++" symbol next to it.  This meant they supported passive HDMI adapters and cables.  Few USB-C ports support HDMI.  If you want HDMI from USB then you'll need an active adapter, probably costing about $100.

MHL is another video standard you may come across.  It supports 4K screens from MHL capable USB ports using inexpensive passive adapters.  It's not very popular though.  I'll see MHL/HDMI combination inputs on TVs and monitors but not too many things will output MHL.  If you are looking to save money then consider MHL gear might be cheap.  Or consider my mention of it merely being more complete in listing your options.

If you haven't already bought that $100 DisplayLink adapter then I expect that is were you will end up.  There's a reason they are popular.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was a pleasure to read about the camping experience. You are a good writer. If I may ask a question. Why did not you vote up a question that makes you write such an amazing essay?